# Anchor tag is not working inside the list

Tags: 2013, razormediator

I have a Template to render the list class with anchor tag, it is working fine in Template Builder as well as in the preview mode in CMS. But in the browser after publishing the Page, I can able to view only the following line of code (No anchor is rendering)

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <span><!-- Start Component Field: {"XPath" : "tcm:Content/custom:/custom:title[1]"} -->Parents and students</span>                    
  </li>
  <li>
    <span><!-- Start Component Field: {"XPath" : "tcm:Content/custom:/custom:title[1]"} -->Principals and heads</span>                    
  </li>
  <li>
</ul>
```

kindly help me to resolve this.

Comment: Could you please **edit** your question and supply a bit more detail, like the source of your Template? I have a feeling you are trying to render a dynamic Component link, and that is not resolved, but I have no clue really since you don't supply enough information in your question.

Comment: Most likely, you're linking to a component that is NOT published currently, and therefore the link is not showing.

Answer (score -1):

Please try below sample dwt code. I hope solve your issue.

```
<ul>
   <li>
 <a tridion:href="@@Component.ID@@">@@HTMLDecode(Component.Fields.Name)@@</a><li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to use Dynamic component in Anchor tag if so then can you publish the component which you are using in anchor tag and then try, can you please share your anchor tag code

Comment: Thanks for helping with this Santosh. We generally find that when you're trying to help someone to get their question clear, it's better to do it in the comments rather than by giving an answer. Once it's clear, you have a much better chance of giving a good answer.